# How to fix cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am getting the following Error:

```
> XXX Created runtime cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions@477b4cdf
>     cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
>     cucumber.runtime.SerenityBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,
> 
>     io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:53)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.instantiateSubclasses(Reflections.java:35)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.loadBackends(Runtime.java:89)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:42)
>     at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenityRuntime.createSerenityEnabledRuntime(CucumberWithSerenityRuntime.java:38)
>     at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenityRuntime.using(CucumberWithSerenityRuntime.java:28)
>     at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity.createRuntime(CucumberWithSerenity.java:58)
>     at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:63)
>     at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity.<init>(CucumberWithSerenity.java:39)
> . . .
> 
>     at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: cucumber.runtime.SerenityBackend.<init>(cucumber.runtime.io.ResourceLoader,
> io.cucumber.stepexpression.TypeRegistry)
>     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
>     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Reflections.newInstance(Reflections.java:45)
>     ... 22 more
> 
>     Process finished with exit code -1
```

It's a Maven project with Serenity.

I hope you can help me with the error, I would be very grateful

Comment: can you give more details? what're you trying to do?

Comment: Could you provide the code to your runner and your dependencies?